# Installing Flask - Structure

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I am about to start learning `Flask`, and I've followed the installation instructions at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installation.

I've followed the `virtualenv` method, as opposed to the system wide installation. I just don't understand what the structure of `virtualenv` and how it relates to Flask.

I ran all the commands in a directory. Does this mean that `virtualenv`, Flask and Jinga2 are all running in that very directory only? Does that mean I will need to set up virtualenv and flask every time I start a flask project in that project's directory?

Secondly, When I navigate outside of the directory, my prompt still has `venv`. How can I stop that?

Comment: I would recommend you to learn virtualenv from some tutorials. It is a handy tool to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtualenv creates an isolated environment where you can install python packages without installing them globally on the system. After you run `venv/bin/activate` any new installed package is then inside this virtualenv (i.e. myproject/venv/lib) and if you exit the virtualenv then the system-wide python would not recognize the packages installed in virtualenv.

It doesn't matter where you install packages using `pip`. When you executed `virtualenv venv` a folder called venv is created and all the installed packages will be copied there.

Finally, in order to exit the virtual environment simply run `deactivate`.

Comment: You can actually run `deactivate` from anywhere while the virtual environment is active - but +1, good answer!

Comment: Great thanks! One more question, each time I activate virtualenv, it starts a new session? Also, can multiple sessions run concurrently? If so, how does it separate the different sessions from each other?